# What was the largest battle fought by ancient Rome?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome, battle

What was the largest battle, by number of participants, in which ancient Rome took part? Not counting sieges.

A quick Google search reveals nothing authoritative, but some discussion threads mention the battles of [Adrianople](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Adrianople_(324)) (295K), [Arausio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Arausio) (280K), [Vercellae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Vercellae) (260K), and -although a bit of a siege- [Alesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Alesia) (260K) - suggested by @ed.hank.

All these numbers come from Wikipedia, and can vary a lot, so I'm looking for something more reliable. My hope is some historian has addressed this, being the question so basic (and quite infantile).

Comment: This question might be answerable if you could provide a time frame that you are specifically looking at, or even era (i.e. Republic, Empire etc).

Comment: @Thomo Republic or Empire, that depends. Which one got the largest battle? ;) I could provide a time frame I guess, but If it's answerable for the Republic and for the Empire, then it should be answerable for both.

Comment: And are you talking all participants or just the Roman numbers?

Comment: @Thomo, Romans, allies and enemies. Battle as a whole.

Comment: If you have done some research, you should include that in your question.

Comment: @user2448131, admittedly I haven't done much research, just enough to see the question is not trivial. And I don't know the answer myself.

Comment: Good question, just a guess but maybe Battle of Alesia, with 60k Roman trrops vs 200k Gauls (80k in Alesia & 120k outside).

Comment: I tried researching this, but there are rather a lot of badly-documented battles with the Persians that have no estimates for one or both sides' force strengths. However, that's where Rome's largest and toughest legions tended to be, and Persia was a major empire as well, so they were likely quite large. For example, for the [Battle of Edessa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Edessa) we don't know how large the Sassanid army was, but we do know it *laid siege* to a Roman army of 70,000.

Comment: @ed.hank Is there a reason you did not make that an answer?

Comment: @T.E.D. didn't Hans Delbruck have a few things to say about sizes of armies from ancient reports? (Can't find my old copy of his books, arrg).

Comment: I know the general consensus is to take Caesar's figures with a very large pinch of salt. He was prone to overstate enemy numbers and underplay his own  to make his victories appear more heroic.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast - i will make it an answer if no one else has a better one, and I can find some appropriate sources on the numbers.  counts in ancient battles are notoriously off.

Comment: The sources are very sketchy but the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Catalaunian_Plains was quite large possibly involving up to 100000 combatants, perhaps not as large as Edessa though. Contemporaneous but dubious sources put the number of dead as high as 150 or 300 thousand, although those figures are quite unlikely.

Comment: @ed.hank please do what you can, it would be great to have an answer.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast - FWIW  Brasidas left a comment in on a now-deleted answer pointing to another battle([Arausio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Arausio)), where Wikipedia claims slightly more participants

Comment: @T.E.D., I deleted the comment because I added its content to the main question, thinking it was good practice.

Comment: @Brasidas - Ah, all I could see was that the whole answer got deleted.

Comment: I would discard battles of Arausio, Vercellae and Alesia. Basically because: 1. Those battles included a lot of civilian population on the barbarian side and 2. The regions which can support large amounts of soldiers living of the local food where mostly central Italy and the east side of the Empire.

Comment: I am not sure on the first 2, but the numbers at Alesia are the most realistic of the bunch.  Caesar goes over the Gaulish muster and though they are high I think personally maybe only 20-30%. I think it can be agreed that the Romans trapped a force at least equal in size in Alesia, and a force of at least double that arrived to relieve the siege.  Extrapolating from that, even if the Romans only fielded 50k , the entire engagement was around 200k for at least a couple days during the main assault. Though I dare not say Alesia was the largest battle, I still think it could have been that big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to wikipedia I would say that [Adrianople](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Adrianople_(324)) is the biggest battle, not only because it was a battle between Romans (so it has sources from both sides), but also because only eastern parts of the Empire and Italy were able to support such huge numbers in an army. While other battles might look great as well, all of them were against barbarians, whose numbers can't be that big counting only warriors.

But I'll also put another battle that might potentially be bigger, [battle of Phillipi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Philippi), during the civil war after Caesar's death. Where 36 legions were in battle, and it might have numbers above 300,000 if those legions had auxiliary forces.